# How do I pass the value entered for an entity field to strip_tags()?

Tags: entities

In the module I am working on, I have an entity field defined with a call to [`BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21BaseFieldDefinition.php/function/BaseFieldDefinition%3A%3Acreate/8.4.x). I would like the user input of this field to be passed to `strip_tags()` or any equivalent Drupal function.

How would I grab the value submitted from users to pass it to that function?